# magento 2: set product image url

Tags: magento2, product-images

I am having image url as

```
http://www.yakshinfotech.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Laptop-Repair.jpg
```

which I need to set for my products. I have tried by setting product image url:

```
$productId = 1;
$product = $this->_product->load(1);
$existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
    unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
}
$product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
$this->_productRepository->save($product);

public function saveImg()
{
   $imageUrl = 'http://s6.favim.com/610/150425/adorable-animal-cat-cute-Favim.com-2680526.jpg'; 
   $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imageUrl, array('image','small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
   $product->save();
}
```

But this code displays error as image not found.
What I need to do to set product image as url?

Answer (score 1):

**Pleaes try with following code**

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Createproduct extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action {

    protected $directoryList;
    protected $file;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directoryList,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\File $file) {

        $this->_resultpageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->directoryList = $directoryList;
        $this->file = $file;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }


    protected function getMediaDirTmpDir()
    {
        return $this->directoryList->getPath($this->directoryList::MEDIA) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'tmp' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    public function setImage($product, $imageUrl, $visible = false, $imageType = [])
    {
        $tmpDir = $this->getMediaDirTmpDir();

        $this->file->checkAndCreateFolder($tmpDir);

        $newFileName = $tmpDir . baseName($imageUrl);


        $result = $this->file->read($imageUrl, $newFileName);
        if ($result) {
            $product->addImageToMediaGallery($newFileName, $imageType, true, $visible);
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function execute() {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load(1);
        $imagePath = "https://domain.com/image.jpg"; // path of the image
            $this->setImage($product, $imagePath, false, $imageType = ['image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail']);
            $product->save();
    }
}
```